# Why doesn't the tag 'antonyms' have the synonym 'antonym'?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retagging

I was just looking through the tag synonyms of [antonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonyms) and discovered that it does not have the synonym [antonym](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonym), in fact, *antonym* is a completely separate tag with just two questions.

As I don't have the necessary reputation, could someone suggest a tag synonym so that *antonym* gets re-mapped onto [antonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonyms)?

Mitch has suggested the synonym, it can be voted on [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/antonyms/synonyms) (1 more to go - we can do it people!).

Please vote on the tag synonym!

Comment: Your wish is granted.

Comment: @Mitch Fantastic, thanks, hopefully, people will vote it up.

Comment: Tag editing is the worst. It's not that easy to have the right rep for a particular tag, and even if you do, most people have no idea that there is the option, and for those that do have an idea, it's really hard to navigate to.

Comment: @Mitch Of course, you can give people the link. >> Vote  [here!](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/antonyms/synonyms). <<

Comment: I think that link led me to cast my first ever vote on a tag synonym.  Didn't even know it was a thing before now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've approved the synonym suggestion.

(And I hope this answer doesn't get flagged for quality due to its length!)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!